# Can you hide a Delayed Blast Fireball in a Minor Illusion?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion

The spell text for [Minor Illusion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/Minor-Illusion) says it cant create any sensory effects:  does this include blocking the glowing of the [Delayed Blast Fireball](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/delayed-blast-fireball) until its detonation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Only if they never saw the original casting

While you may be able to hide the glowing bead, you won't be able to hide the yellow light flashing to it's destination.

*Delayed Blast Fireball* states (PHB 230-1):

> A beam of yellow light flashes from your pointing finger, then condenses to linger at a chosen point within range as a glowing bead for the duration.

*Minor Illusion* can be (PHB 260):

> no larger than a 5' cube

The bead is likely contained within that 5' minor illusion, but the path it takes to get there can still be seen. This applies whether you took the action to create the *Minor Illusion* before or after you cast the *Delayed Blast Fireball*.

If no one was there to witness the casting, then it would be possible to conceal the bead within a *Minor Illusion*.

Comment: Although one may be able to convince the unwise that the spell was miscast or fizzled, if that is a thing in the campaign.

Comment: What if you lured someone into an area where DBF was already cast?  Could you succesfully hide the bead?

Comment: @SeeDerekEngineer I see no reason why not. I adjusted the Lead of my answer accordingly.